# Bitwise logical operator ~

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

[image]

My question is how it became -6 when do the negation ?

Edit : Let's say like this, if we need to represent 6 on 2's complement it should be 110.But on the 2nd row of above is having '4294967290' (decimal) value when It has been converted by using cal **[Here](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-decimal-converter)**
So how can it be a -6 then ?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes.I need to know how ~5 became -6 ?

Comment: Because that is the two's complement representation of -6.

Comment: ...which is how integer values are stored... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: It's not specific to JavaScript. Two's complement is used in almost all programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

The negation as you call it is a strict bit inversion, but decimal values in JavaScript are handled as twos-complement.

So you'd basically need '~5 + 1' to get to the equivalent representation as '-5'.

> In two's-complement representation, positive numbers are simply represented as themselves, and negative numbers are represented by the two's complement of their absolute value

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement for more details.